# Como recorrer una lista con Foreach

Tags: c#, lista, foreach

Hola necesito comparar dos listas,(en ambas listas tengo codigos de pintura, y cantidad de pintura usada, necesito ver cuales codigos son iguales para ver si en la primer lista tiene mas, igual o menos pintura que en la segunda y agregarlo en la tercera lista) como puedo hacer para recorrer las listas mediante un foreach

```
List<ClaseAS400> Clase400 = new List<ClaseAS400>();
List<ClaseSQL> claseSql = new List<ClaseSQL>();

ClaseDiferencia claseDiferencia = new ClaseDiferencia();

foreach(var Elemento in Clase400)
{
            
}
```

Comment: Lo que yo haria es usar dos foreach, uno dentro de otro eh ir comparando los elementos con un if buscando comparaciones, en caso de que queras guardar los valores iguales o diferentes los guardaria en una tercera variable, si estas usando sql, el mimso sql tiene opciones que te permiten hacer eso, no recuerdo bien si era el **join** o otro, seria de leer bien la documentacion que en este momento no recuerdo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero cual es el problema?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres comparar? tamaño de ambas listas? buscar si un objeto de una lista tiene propiedad igual a objeto de otra lista? su pregunta señor está muy abierta tiene que dar un poco mas de detalle

Comment: Votaré la pregunta de forma negativa porque: 1- Gustavo no demostró ningún esfuerzo en investigar cómo funciona el ciclo foreach; y 2- El título de la pregunta no se corresponde con su contenido: "Cómo comparar. . ."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando **Linq** puedes hacer esto:

```
bool sonIguales = Clase400.SequenceEqual(claseSql);

if(sonIguales)
{
   //código
}
```

Aquí se usa el **método SequenceEqual** el cual sirve para comparar dos listas.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: yo esperaria a que aclare.. tiene una clase que se llama claseDiferencia ... para mi.. quiere sacar las diferencias entre las listas...

Comment: Graciaaaas! Me ha servido, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Gustavo si la respuesta te sirvio por favor marcala como aceptada, gracias