# Como comparar dos listas y en una tercera mostrar las diferencias de cantidades de un campo en C#

Tags: c#, foreach

Ya tengo mis dos listas:

```
List<Clase1> Clase1 = new List<Clase1>();
List<Clase2> Clase2 = new List<Clase2>();
```

En ambas listas tengo 5 campos (Orden, Linea, orden2, Pintura, Cantidad) y necesito mediante numero de orden, Linea y pintura comparar si alguno de la lista 2 coincide con la 1, en caso de coincidir necesito restar la cantidad de la 2 lista con la de la primera para ver si tiene mas cantidad de pintura o menos o si están iguales en ambas listas.

Comment: Lectura muy recomendable: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 TL;DR? Edita la pregunta y agrega el código que has intentado. Saludos.

Comment: Debes dar mas detalles para poderte ayudar, tu problema no lo explicas de forma clara.

Comment: Para entender mejor la pregunta y el resultado que se busca, sugiero agregar las definiciones de **Clase1** y **Clase2** que son los tipos que se usan en las listas, además de un ejemplo de cuál sería la entrada y la salida que se obtendría.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como recorrer una lista con Foreach](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/552191/como-recorrer-una-lista-con-foreach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tengo reputación suficiente para comentar, así que lo escribo como respuesta.
He hecho una prueba con la información que tenemos (si alguien puede mejorar el código es libre de hacerlo):

Clases:

```
    class Clase1
    {
        int Orden;
        int Linea;
        int orden2;
        string Pintura;
        float Cantidad;

        public Clase1(int orden, int linea, int orden2, string pintura, float cantidad)
        {
            Orden = orden;
            Linea = linea;
            this.orden2 = orden2;
            Pintura = pintura;
            Cantidad = cantidad;
        }

        public int Orden1 { get => Orden; set => Orden = value; }
        public int Linea1 { get => Linea; set => Linea = value; }
        public int Orden2 { get => orden2; set => orden2 = value; }
        public string Pintura1 { get => Pintura; set => Pintura = value; }
        public float Cantidad1 { get => Cantidad; set => Cantidad = value; }
    }
    class Clase2
    {
        int Orden;
        int Linea;
        int orden2;
        string Pintura;
        float Cantidad;

        public Clase2(int orden, int linea, int orden2, string pintura, float cantidad)
        {
            Orden = orden;
            Linea = linea;
            this.orden2 = orden2;
            Pintura = pintura;
            Cantidad = cantidad;
        }

        public int Orden1 { get => Orden; set => Orden = value; }
        public int Linea1 { get => Linea; set => Linea = value; }
        public int Orden2 { get => orden2; set => orden2 = value; }
        public string Pintura1 { get => Pintura; set => Pintura = value; }
        public float Cantidad1 { get => Cantidad; set => Cantidad = value; }
    }
```

La función:

```
 private static void Metodo1()
    {

        List<Clase2> Clase2 = new List<Clase2>();
        List<Clase1> Clase1 = new List<Clase1>();
        Clase1.Add(new Clase1(1, 1, 1, "Pintura1", 20));
        Clase2.Add(new Clase2(1, 1, 1, "Pintura1", 20));
        Clase1.Add(new Clase1(2, 2, 2, "Pintura2", 30));
        Clase2.Add(new Clase2(2, 2, 2, "Pintura2", 10));
        Clase1.Add(new Clase1(3, 2, 2, "Pintura3", 10));
        Clase2.Add(new Clase2(3, 3, 2, "Pintura3", 30));
        StringBuilder Resultado = new StringBuilder();
        Resultado.AppendLine("-----Resultados----");
        foreach (Clase1 clase1 in Clase1)
        {
            try
            {
                Clase2 clase2;
                if ((clase2 = Clase2.Where(item => (item.Orden1 == clase1.Orden1 && item.Linea1 == clase1.Linea1 && item.Pintura1 == clase1.Pintura1)).First()) != null) //LINQ para encontrar el primer elemento que coincide.
                {
                    if (clase2.Cantidad1 - clase1.Cantidad1 < 0)
                    {
                        Resultado.AppendLine(clase2.Pintura1 + " Mas Pequeño");
                    }
                    else if (clase2.Cantidad1 - clase1.Cantidad1 == 0)
                    {
                        Resultado.AppendLine(clase2.Pintura1 + " Igual");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Resultado.AppendLine(clase2.Pintura1 + " Mas Grande");
                    }

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No existe o ha fallado la comparacion");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Resultado.ToString());
    }
```

Comentarios del Código:

La función se basa en iterar la lista de la clase1 y comparar mediante una comanda de linq la cual devuelve el primer objeto que coincide en la lista de la clase2. El try es necesario, ya que si no encuentra ninguno que coincida, el Linq genera una excepción de null.
Después se compara las cantidades entre las dos clases y se determina en que condición están las cantidades. En mi caso, puesto que era por consola, use un StringBuilder para hacer el output al final.

Output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]